# socket io: how to pass paramter to disconnet socket event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I am using socket io for building a chat app.

when "user x" is disconneting from the chat I want to print to the console log: "bye user x".

for that to happen I need to pass as a paramater the user_name to the disconnect event.

problem is that I don't know how to pass data to the disconnect event:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){...})
```

it is being called automaticly when user disconnected.

I ned to have something like

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(user_name){
    console.log('bye '+user_name);
})
```

but if that is possible (is it?) then how can I pass this parameter in the client side (my case, angular)?

my complete socket io server.js code is below.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    io.emit('chat_message', "welcome");

    socket.on('room', function(room) {
        socket.join(room);
    });

    socket.on('chat_message', function(data){
        socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('chat_message',data.msg);
    });
    socket.on('info_message', function(data){
        socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('info_message',data.msg);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('bye '+socket.id);
        io.emit('chat message', "Bye");

    });
});
```

Comment: I assume you will need a helper function that initially stores the room, user and socket id in an object/array on connection. On disconnect, you will be able to match the socket.id to a username in the object/array and display as needed.

Comment: Thanks, the socket id is unique for each user or unique per room?

Comment: Seems like it: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/ - `Each Socket in Socket.IO is identified by a random, unguessable, unique identifier Socket#id. For your convenience, each socket automatically joins a room identified by this id.`

Comment: i don't think you can: when `disconnect` fires, it's already too late to do anything...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass data to the disconnect event.  You can however attach your own properties to the `socket` object at some earlier point or you can keep your own map of sockets with additional information.

You just need to make sure that the server knows the user name for each socket (I can't tell from your question if the user name is a client-side or server-side piece of data).  Then, you can just attach it to the socket object as a property.  After doing that, when you then get the disconnect event, you can just look at that property on the socket that is disconnecting.

So, wherever the username info comes from, you set that property on the socket object at the time the server knows what it as and then you can do this for the disconnect:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('bye ' + socket.user_name);
});
```

Or, if the user name is in a cookie, you can fetch that cookie value at any time by parsing `socket.handshake.headers.cookie`.